# ROS2 run bash script

Tags: ros, ros2, bash, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to run a bash script as a node liek the following:

> ros2 run package script.sh

I know this is possible in ROS1, however I cannot find the right way to do it in ROS2.

Do you have any idea ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367235/ros2-run-bash-script/) by [alexisthethe](https://answers.ros.org/users/64916/alexisthethe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-12-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`ros2 run` currently looks in the install subdirectory `lib/${PROJECT_NAME}`. So, it should work if you install your bash script to that location, for example:

```
install(
  PROGRAMS script.sh
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})
```

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2020-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0